# Of people who took at least one ride, what's the average number of metro lines they rode?

Tags: sql, activerecord, count, distinct

I'm trying to write a SQL or ActiveRecord query to answer this question: "Of people who took at least one ride, what is the average number of metro lines that they've departed from?"

The schema is as follows:

- **Ride:** A trip from one location to another. `user_id` for the User, `location_id` for the Location.
- **Location:** A location is a stop along a line. The location has a `line_id` indicating what line it's on. A location belongs to one line.
- **Line:** A line is a series of related metro stops, its locations.
- **User:** The person who took the trip.

It looks like I need to do two things:

- Given the Rides joined to their locations, count the number of distinct `[rides.user_id, locations.line_id]` combinations.
- Divide that by the number of users who've taken at least one ride.

The result will be the average, and thus the answer to the question.

1. Does that sound right?
2. If so, what's the best way to do that?

I'm using Rails, so if I can express this in ARel or AR syntax without having to drop into SQL, that would be great. But I'll take what I can get.

---

A commenter asked for an example. Let's imagine that the data looks something like this:

```
rides                     locations
======================    =====================
user_id    location_id    location_id   line_id
1          1              1             1
1          1              2             1
1          1              3             2
1          1              4             3
2          1              5             4
2          2              6             5
2          3
3          3
3          4
3          5
3          6
```

We can see that user 1 took 4 rides, user 2 took 3 rides, and user 3 took 4 rides. These rides were to `[1, 3, 4]` distinct *locations*, but only `[1, 2, 4]` distinct *lines*. Thus, the average number of lines that a given user rode was `(1 + 2 + 4) / 3`, or `2.33...`.

Comment: It looks complicated... Can you post some sample data for all tables and desired o/p

Comment: @Venk: I provided an example to clear up any confusion.

Comment: 1 + 2 + 4 is the number of distinct _lines_ that had rides from each user. User 1 traveled on 1 line, user 2 traveled on 2 lines, and user 3 traveled on 4 lines.

Comment: please correct me if I am wrong .. by **line** you mean to say about line column value corresponding to location traveled by users right?
user 1 traveled on location 1 only .. line used is line_id 1.
user 2 traveled on 1,2,3 locations means line_id used is 1,1,2 - till now distinct line_id [1,2].. user traveled on location_id [3,4,5,6] line_id used [2,3,4,5] then distinct line_id used should be [1,2,3,4,5] .. right .. count for division should be 5 .. isn't it?

Comment: @pratikgarg No, it should be 7. User 1 rode 1 line. User 2 rode 2 lines. user 3 rode 4 lines. 1 + 2 + 4 is 7, not 5. Remember, we're trying to calculate the _average number of lines **per user**_.

Comment: what do you mean by `[1,2,4] distinct line` ?

Comment: if you are taking about distinct user then in question there should be [1,2,3] distinct user .. and count of distinct user **3** will use as divisor.. right na sir ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL:

```
select avg(ln) as avg_lines
from (
    select user_id, count(distinct line_id) as ln
    from rides r join locations l on (r.location_id = l.location_id)
    group by user_id
)
```